# Talend SOAP issue

Tags: soap, soapui, talend

I have an issue using tsoap component, my Soap request works on SoapUI, but doesn't work on Talend:

SoapUI:

[image]

Talend:

[image]

Could you help ?

Comment: What is the error you're getting in Talend ?

Comment: I have this error message :  SAAJ0009: Message send failed
[FATAL]: api.e2time_0_1.e2time - tSOAP_1 java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much to go on here, but I believe this has to do with the https certificate missing from java. You can fix it by installing the certificate in your java. Follow these steps :

1. Export the certificate from your web browser. In Google Chrome, open
   the endpoint url, then press F12, then go to security tab in Developer window. Click "View Certificate", go to Details tab, and export to a .cer file (click "Copy to file", and just follow the wizard using default settings at each step).
2. Now that you have your .cer file, you can install it by following
   these steps. Open a cmd with admin rights, then navigate to the bin
   directory of your java installation (the one used by Talend), and
   run the following command :

   `keytool -import -alias e2timeCertificate -file "/path/to/mycert.cer" -keystore "<JAVA_HOME>\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit`

/path/to/mycert.cer is the absolute path to your .cer file which you exported in step 1.
replace "JAVA_HOME" with the path to your java installation (in my case it is in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131). Make sur to check the paths before executing the command.

You should now be able to access the webservice from Talend.